# How to read the busy flag on LCD?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd

I have a standard 16x2 LCD screen and I have it hooked up to my Arduino UNO via a I2C backpack (4-bit mode).

Since I want to learn about the lcd at a lower level I’ve decided not to use the LCD library and instead use the Wire library.

I have writing to the LCD working fine so now I want to understand how to read from it. I thought trying to read the busy flag was a good start.  (I currently delay() after to the LCD which seems to be the most popular solution).

According to the LCD documentation it requires that the RS bit be set to 0 and RW bit to 1. I have a attached the code below.  For some reason it always reads 0x2.

I also read the busy flag right after writing to the screen and it always screws up every other letter.  E.g. if I write 'k' twice to the screen, the first 'k' shows up fine, but the second time it becomes a 'f'.  I am suspecting writing to the LCD before reading is screwing up the data processing.  If I don't attempt to read the flag, all the characters show up correctly.

Here is the code.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

```
#define ENABLE (1 << 2)
#define BACKLIGHT (1 << 3)

#define READ (1 << 1)

byte readReq = BACKLIGHT | ENABLE | READ;
Wire.beginTransmission(0x3F);
Wire.write(readReq);
Wire.write(readReq & ~ENABLE);// write 1st nibble
Wire.write(readReq);
Wire.write(readReq & ~ENABLE); //write 2nd nibble

Wire.endTransmission();

Wire.requestFrom(0x3F, 2);    

while (Wire.available() < 2) {}   


byte firstNibble = Wire.read(); //always reads 0x2
byte secondNibble = Wire.read(); //always reads 0x2
Serial.println(firstNibble, HEX);
Serial.println(secondNibble, HEX);
```

Comment: What is this I2C backpack thing you are using?

Comment: Not the exact model, but something like this: https://goo.gl/images/ftHFNx

Comment: Does it have the same chip on it?

Comment: It is a PCF8574AT